# VB6 Migrating to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, vb6-migration

I am migrating an application from VB6 to C#, which are used Recordset. My question is: which object is the "equivalent" to VB6 recordset in C# or at least the one to use?

Comment: Or you use the ADO import library to still use the Recordset and all the family (not recommended) or you learn ADO.NET and switch your code to it. (Long road ahead but....)

Comment: [Migrating Code and Concepts from ADO "Classic" to ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971478.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that the closest thing you'd find would be a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is part of a [DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss7fbaez%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Of course, with the variety of fantastic ORMs out there these days (Dapper, Simple, ServiceStack.OrmLite, EF, etc), perhaps you can use this as an opportunity to upgrade your methodology practices at the same time, or even just use a cleaner IDataReader approach.

Comment: DataTable is the answer. Thanks!